# How to show $\Gamma (n)$ is convergent if and only $n>0$?

Tags: convergence-divergence

How to show $\Gamma (n)$ is convergent if and only $n>0$  where $\Gamma (n)$ is the gamma function.

Comment: Well a function value can't really be convergent... I suspect you are asking about the convergence of $\int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}\,dt$

Comment: Yes i'm asking that but i didn't understand the difference.

Comment: The question's ill-posed. It seems to be you meant to ask to show the integral defining $\;\Gamma(t)\;$ indeed converges iff $\;\text{Re}(t)>0\;$ . You must know the gamma function can be analitically continued to the whole complex plane without the non-positive integers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that $\displaystyle\int_0^1t^{x-1}e^{-t}\,dt$ converges. Use the convergence of $\displaystyle\int_0^1t^{x-1}\,dt$ and the continuity of $e^{-t}$.

Show that $\displaystyle\int_1^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}\,dt$ converges. Use the convergence of $\displaystyle\int_1^\infty e^{-t/2}\,dt$ and that $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t^{x-1}}{e^{t/2}}=0$.